# Power Grid - Simpler Resource Grid

Tags: game-accessories, power-grid

I've heard that there is a printable chart for Power Grid somewhere online, possibly [BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/).

Said chart breaks down the players & steps into individual cards that are more convenient than the bulky back of the rule book.

Something like this:

```
Players: 4
   Step 1 Step 2 Step 3
Oil   1       2       3
Coal  2       3       4
etc.
```

Does anyone know where I can find this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [any of these](http://boardgamegeek.com/files/thing/2651?sort=hot&languageid=&B1=Apply)? I've ordered that list by popularity, so the stuff at the top should be the most useful. There are lots and lots of summaries and crib sheets available. Which one works best for you is really a question of personal taste.

Comment: I don't know why that was so hard for me to find, but yes! [This](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/6714/power-grid-reference-sheets-pdf) is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I think the key is finding the game on BGG, then clicking on "files", then looking through said files for what you're looking for. This is what eluded me.

Comment: Having each of the number of players info on separate pages is great! I'm going to have to print these. :)